search() finds hit on the current line only if column is 1
Consider the following snippet:
vim9script

   var foo = 3

If go on line 3 and I run :echo search('^\s*var', 'cnW') I get the value 3 only if the cursor is on columns 1. If keep the cursor on the same line but I move it on another column, then the search results always returns 0.
I would expect to have 3 as search result no matter from which column I run the command.
Is the observed behavior normal?

You can narrow it down to :echo search('^', 'cnW') which will always return the following line's number unless the cursor is in the first column.
I'd say the behavior is normal. See :help /^, it stands for start-of-line and it will match only the start of a line, i.e. the first column.
If you don't want that, remove ^ from your search pattern.
You might also use a function or command that searches the whole line instead of from the cursor position.
The comment stating that leaving out the z flag implies the whole line is searched is incorrect as can be read from :help search().
The first lines read (emphasis mine)

The search starts at the cursor position (you can use cursor() to set it).

while further it says about the z flag:

'z'   start searching at the cursor column instead of zero

This redundancy is clarified by the paragraph a little bit further down (again, emphasis mine):

When the 'z' flag is not given, forward searching always
starts in column zero and then matches before the cursor are skipped.

There's a minor contradiction between where searching starts and where matches start.
Overall, I'd say everything makes sense and is spelled out explicitly.
I'm not entirely sure how setting the z flag should matter from a user's perspective.
There's probably an edge case I can't think of right now.

As a workadound I am actually using a cursor(line('.'), 1) before the search(). The point is that I want to search all the lines that start with a certain pattern, including the current line, regardless of the cursor position but the only way seem to move the cursor on col = 1 before starting the search. Also, I m not using the z flag in search() which suggests that the search should start from col = 1 anyway, but it does not seem the case.

@Barzi2001 I failed to read the whole of :help search() last night. See my recent edit. There's a paragraph explaining that no implicit start at column 1 is supposed to happen.

Thanks. I don’t  see the point of that z flag either in common practice. There may be some edge case - but I am not entirely sure either. I think it is way less edgy the need of starting the search from the first column.
